# React: render concatenated component based on imported list of components

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

I'm not sure if what I'm trying to do is even possible, or if there's a better way to accomplish my goal. Any insight would be massively helpful.

#### Context:

- I have a directory full of components that render inline SVGs
- These components are gathered in an `IconsIndex.js` file and are exported as such:

`export { default as Rocket } from "./Rocket";`

- I am importing the index to have access to my icon library from any given component:

`import * as Icon from "./icons/IconsIndex";`

This allows me to essentially do: `<Icon.Rocket />` which renders the SVG component perfectly.

What I'd like to do is be able to have the `<Icon />` component be able to be more dynamic from parent components.

**For example:**

```
class ResourceBlock extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BlockContainer>
        <BlockIcon>
          <Icon.Rocket />
        </BlockIcon>
        <BlockTitle>{this.props.caption}</BlockTitle>
        <Button>{this.props.buttonText}</Button>
      </BlockContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

This outputs the `Rocket` icon everywhere the `ResourceBlock` component is called. What I'd like to be able to do is something like this:

```
<ResourceBlock icon={Icon.Rocket} caption="Lorem..." buttonText="..." />
```

Is this possible? How can I achieve this level of flexibility with our icons?

The key is to keep the SVGs as decoupled as possible, so wrapping them all in an additional `<Icon />` component isn't appealing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure:

```
<ResourceBlock icon={<Icon.Rocket />} caption="Lorem..." buttonText="..." />

class ResourceBlock extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <BlockContainer>
        <BlockIcon>
          {this.props.icon}
        </BlockIcon>
        <BlockTitle>{this.props.caption}</BlockTitle>
        <Button>{this.props.buttonText}</Button>
      </BlockContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

It's a little odd, but [in JSX if the node name is lowercase it will be translated as an html tag](https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/f1f4ba40816e7d7848ad), not a component reference. So just assign your icon property to an uppercase local const and render it that way:

```
class ResourceBlock extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const Icon = this.props.icon;
    return (
      <BlockContainer>
        <BlockIcon>
          <Icon />
        </BlockIcon>
        <BlockTitle>{this.props.caption}</BlockTitle>
        <Button>{this.props.buttonText}</Button>
      </BlockContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

Used just like you had it:

```
<ResourceBlock icon={Icon.Rocket} caption="Lorem..." buttonText="..." />
```

Comment: Could it be possible to use the alternative notation for object properties, and pass only the icon? `<ResourceBlock icon='Rocket' ... />` and then in the render method `<Icon[this.props.icon] />` ; could that work?

Comment: @Jaxx That syntax doesn't work, but you could certainly pass a string to lookup a component reference on the `Icon` imported namespace, you'd just still need to assign it to a local const with uppercase name in order to render it.

Comment: This threw several errors for me, notably `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components)` - it's possible I'd need to rejigger some other things in my app to get it to work? I appreciate the quick response, and I like the readability of the local assignation.

Comment: @JoshKennedy Sounds like what you passed to `icon` was not a valid react type (valid type = a string or a component reference -- *not* a rendered element).

Comment: @Aaron entirely possible - still getting my feet wet with React. Thanks for the assist!